# Can't install angular2 - keep getting npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs'

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm

Somethings weird - I'm trying to install the `@angular/cli` on my ubuntu 16. However everytime I run:

```
sudo npm install -g angular-cli
```

However I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/fs'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2017-07-10T10_16_30_140Z-debug.log
```

Opening the log file shows the following trace:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'angular-cli' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.3
3 info using node@v8.1.3
4 verbose npm-session d7ce68b94a383c36
5 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
5 verbose stack     at evalmachine.<anonymous>:40:20
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js:11:1)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
5 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cmd-shim/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:3:27)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
6 verbose cwd /home/ali
7 verbose Linux 4.4.0-75-generic
8 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
9 verbose node v8.1.3
10 verbose npm  v5.0.3
11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
12 error Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have the following versions of nodejs and npm installed:

```
$ node -v
$ v8.1.3
$ npm -v
$ 5.0.3
```

I've been trying for a while now and can't understand whats going on. Any ideas guys?

Comment: Sounds similar to this bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9377

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth indeed, got the same problem, I had to reinstall Node, and it worked :)

Comment: I've tried reinstalling node but it didn't seem to work - I did a sudo apt-get remove nodejs, and reinstalled it but to no avail - :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try this

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I tried that as well - it gives the exact same error irrespective of what version of node I have it seems...